# Tor and MITM SSL

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, tor

In my company they have MITM/SSL in following way.
There is a proxy to whom all PCs connect.
Now the company installed some trusted certificate authority (e.g. ISSUER-COMPANY-NAME) on our computers.
When I go to facebook it shows me that it has certificate signed by the
issuer that was installed by our company.
I am curious will Tor hide my traffic in such setting? will they see say my facebook password if I use Tor?

Comment: I think firefox uses its own Certificate store, even on windows (having set up custom CAs in firefox and windows), so unless that certificate is imported into Tor Browser (Specialized firefox), then I don't think they would be able to. However, if the certificate that is installed on your computer is indeed accepted by tor browser/firefox, they could decrypt it, but only if they had a way to capture the traffic coming out, which they would be unable to do unless they were running the exit node. Overall I think the answer is no, but someone more knowledgeable should be able to chime in.

Comment: In short: Tor traffic can not be decrypted by company-wide SSL-Interception. What could happen though is that your traffic gets completely blocked.